# Entity Framework sqlite .Contains, CHARINDEX and unicode

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-6

I have a WPF application that uses Sqlite as database, using Entity Framework 6.
The problem is that when I try to filter out values using Queryable.Contains, in case data is of [Georgian Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgian_(Unicode_block)) characters, results do not get filtered out.

Consider something like this

```
        using (var db = GetDb())
        {
            var patientsQuery = db.Patients.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchParam))
            {
                patientsQuery = patientsQuery.Where(patient => (patient.FirstName + " " + patient.LastName).ToLower().Contains(searchParam.ToLower()));
            }

            var patients = patientsQuery.ToList();
        }
```

Strange thing is, when I Inspect the `patients` variable, it shows **all** the patients from db that have First and Last names set to unicode characters and results to not get filtered by searchParam. If I have 6 records, 3 of which are georgian unicode and one of them matches searchParam, query returns all three records.

Moreover, what is bothering me most is that when I explore generated sql from patientsQuery variable or database log output, it shows this

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[PatientId] AS [PatientId], 
[Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Extent1].[BirthDate] AS [BirthDate], 
[Extent1].[CreateDate] AS [CreateDate], 
[Extent1].[ProfileFolder] AS [ProfileFolder], 
[Extent1].[Comment] AS [Comment]
FROM [Patients] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (((CHARINDEX(LOWER(@p__linq__0), LOWER(CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[FirstName] IS NULL) THEN '' ELSE [Extent1].[FirstName] END || ' ' || CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[LastName] IS NULL) THEN '' ELSE [Extent1].[LastName] END))) > 0) OR ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [PatientImages] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[PatientId] = [Extent2].[PatientId]) AND ((CHARINDEX(@p__linq__1, [Extent2].[Comment])) > 0)
))) OR ((CHARINDEX(@p__linq__2, [Extent1].[Comment])) > 0)


-- p__linq__0: 'არჩ' (Type = String)

-- p__linq__1: 'არჩ' (Type = String)

-- p__linq__2: 'არჩ' (Type = String)

-- Executing at 2/12/2017 11:08:03 PM +04:00

-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SQLiteDataReader
```

But there is no **charindex** in Sqlite, so I cannot really understand what is happening behind the scenes and how do I see exact query that is used to retrieve data. In case the data and search string are non unicode, the exact same code works fine and filters out everything correctly.

Im lost and any help would be great.

Comment: System.Data.SQLite adds some extra SQL functions, including CHARINDEX - https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/artifact/cf472240cc05d3be

Comment: Thanks @ErikEJ. That has cleared one confusion (that I was not able to execute queries from sqlite management studios). But do you have any idea why would unicode cause problems?

Comment: No idea- what does you table definition look like? Is FirstName of type TEXT? You should be able to execute the query if you use my SQLite Toolbox, as it uses System.Data.SQLite

Comment: @ErikEJ I tried text, ntext, nvarchar and all of them still the same. Thanks to you I executed the statement from visual studio and results are the same.
From what I observed, it feels like CHARINDEX checks count of characters (and not the actual characters) when unicode and if length of target value is not less than search string, it returns record.